# Burninate / merge the [networking] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

The [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking) tag (x15986) needs to go.

About half the new questions asked in this tag are actually non-programming networking questions.

Can we get rid of it?

Presumably the existing [network-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-programming) tag can take all the programming questions.

It's probably a bit too much to go through by hand. An automated merge of the [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking) questions to [network-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-programming) might be a good idea.

I don't think synonymizing them would be a good option as the new off-topic questions would be likely to keep coming.

We might even consider blacklisting [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking).

The [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking) tag's wiki page mentions [the great cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012), which is gone now, but [the only archive I found](http://web.archive.org/web/20120504045242/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) doesn't mention it.

Or should we try to get the non-programming questions closed first? [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/191794) (x256)  are a few questions with **just** the networking tag - presumably most of them should be closed. We can probably extend this to any question with the networking tag and just any of the following tags (with nothing else): windows, linux, unix, router, ssh-tunnel, wifi, multicast, broadcast, dhcp, ubuntu, arp, security, dns, osx, nat, network-protocols, subnet, etc.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. Its rather annoying as there are many questions that border both networking and programming. The networking tag should probably be removed, with only the network-programming tag allow to survive and subtly enforce the style of question upon the user.

Comment: It's a little unfortunate to see `network-programming` occupied by what is essentially "sockets", as well as a handful of other APIs.  Because there is a category of "network programming" problems in optimization (mental association with "bin packing" and "knapsack", but network programs are ones like flow covering, etc)

Comment: They're coming in at more than one an hour! How can all those induhviduals type, when they obviously can't read!?